# OData Connected Service vs OData V4 Client Code Generator

Tags: c#, odata, odata-v4

- [OData Connected Service](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b343d0eb-6493-44c2-b558-13a0408d013f)
- [OData  V4 Client Code Generator](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937)

I know that these extensions are used to generate client code based on Odata service.

1. What is the difference between OData Connected Service vs OData v4
   Client Code Generator extension.
2. What is the purpose of these extensions?
3. When should I use OData Connected Service and when should I use
   Client Code Generator?

Can anyone explain the pros and cons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After doing some Investigation i found the answer.
There are no differences between these two extensions. Both tools are generating  proxy classes based on same T4 template. There is no differences in generated code as well.

The only difference is the OData Connected Service is, Visual studio 2015 supports GUI wizard to generate the client code.